# Yamaha Clavinova CVP309GP USB File Transfer

Tags: piano, digital-piano

Let me start off by stating I am not a musician, I am an IT guy.  My wife however is a musician and just started as the music director of our church.  They have a Yamaha Clavinova 309GP.  Currently they have a 3.5" floppy drive connected to the interface via USB and I was wondering if there is a way to directly transfer the files to a laptop via USB or other medium?  I have tried a USB Flash drive but the piano is giving a error that states the disk is not formatted.

Comment: I do have the manual and it mentions USB devices but the list provided is model/brand specific and are all discontinued.  I will look for a drive that uses MBR and see if that works.  If you list out your response and an answer I will mark it accordingly

Comment: as first you need to format the usb device by your cvp and not formated by computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older devices (or modern equipment that uses outdated device hardware or software; I know of Enterprise Grade Workgroup Printers that reject current USB drives as too large, sigh) can always be problematic. For USB some ideas would be to:

- Find the manual for the device and see what it indicates as supported (and also what year the device came out, which may give clues as to what the maximum supported filesystem and such will be).
- Find a smaller USB drive; some equipment will have limits and not be able to read drives that exceed those limits.
- Reformat the usb drive with MBR instead of the newer GPT partition format. This may require delving into the formatting and partitioning tools for your OS.
- Use an older filesystem; FAT32 is common though older devices may use or require older versions of a filesystem. Again, check the manual for the device and the format and partition tool docs on your OS. Creating partitions less the entire drive size may help, unless the device only sees the total drive size which is too large and then no workey. Doesn't hurt to try...
- See if a USB cable between the device and a computer causes anything to appear on the computer automagically. This may require checking the manual for the device (to turn on file sync) or drivers installed on the computer (problematic if the drivers are not available for modern OS).

Used hardware sources may be of help, e.g. to purchase older flash drives or if available try local music or electronics stores where they may have experience messing around with such equipment. Local hacker or maker spaces may also have folks with experience with electronics, USB, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Look up USB floppy drive emulators on Youtube. They allow you to use a USB flash drive in place of floppy discs, with one drive giving you tons of floppys worth of data storage. There's plenty of videos about keyboards that use this system as well. They're pretty cheap too, just make sure you get the right format/size for the system.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to [this manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/374549/Yamaha-Clavinova-Cvp-307.html?page=190#manual).

Note, that the idea most instruments have concerning USB is quite limited, so practically nothing can be taken for granted just because the plug fits mechanically.

The essential information seems to be this quote:

> Before purchasing USB storage devices, please consult your Yamaha dealer, or an authorized Yamaha distributor (see list at end of the Owner's Manual) for advice, or see the following web page:[clavinova page](http://www.yamahaclavinova.com/)